# Required field of html is not working with django template syntax

Tags: html, django

Required field html validation not working with django its not asking to select from the list do anyone knows how to solve it only its working when I remove the django template syntax

```
<select name="assignee" required id="assignee" class="form-control">
   {% for user in b %}
   <option>{{user.firstname}} {{user.lastname}}</option>
   {% endfor %}
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an empty option before the for loop

```
<option value=''>Select</option>
```